# Salesforce trial force template is invalid

Tags: appexchange

I just updated my package, created a new trial force template and installed the new package in that order. Afterwards, I generated a new template.

When I go to the publishing console, it's not able to retrieve the template. I get an error message "We've encountered a problem with one or more of your trial templates. Please log a case in the Salesforce.com Partner Portal so that we can assist you."

What is the problem with the template?What we need to do so that the publishing console can access the template?

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008uV5IAI) as well. The steps needed are

1. Log a case in the Partner Portal. Request that you would like to make that Developer Edition org your Trialforce Master Organization.
2. Once the case is resolved, you can enable a Branded Login Site or Branded Email Set, and configure your trialforce instances. Please check out the Spring’12 release notes for instructions and information: https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_spring12_release_notes.pdf
3. Once you have created your first Trialforce template, log a case in the partner portal to request that trialforce signup form be configured for your trialforce template (include the template id in the case).
4. In return, you will get a sample HTML form with the proper values to hardcode in the signup page. From there, you can brand the web page as you like.